# .NET Membership

Tags: asp.net, membership

Hi I am trying out the membership features for .NET and I am using the ASP.NET Web application Administration Tool.  My question is where is the user data being stored?  I checked my databases and I cannot find it anywhere.  I also tried to look for any information within Providers in the admin tool but I still could not locate a path.  Can someone help me out?  Thanks.

[EDIT]
Nothing is in the App_Data folder.

Also I was wondering when I right click App_Data and try to add a database, there is no option to do so.  (Add New Item).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a file called ASPNETDB.MDF in the App_Data folder of your web application project.  That's a SQL Express database file.

Edit: Try looking in the App_Data folder in Windows Explorer.  It may be on the disk but not showing up in the project inside of Visual Studio.

https://web.archive.org/web/20210513220018/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

Comment: You are correct.  Is there a way I can get this as a table on my SQL server?  Do I attach the db?

Comment: Probably because the admin tool created the file but didn't add it to the project. You can add it to the project by right-clicking on the the App_Data directory and choosing Add > Existing Item.

Comment: Adding the tables to your database server is fairly simple, but involves a lot of little steps. I'd suggest following the instructions found here: http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/040506-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think, it would create a database by name aspnet by default.

Check it :)

Comment: There is no such db on my server.

Answer (score 1):

It's saved in a database file under your ASP.NET application's App_Data folder.

You can configure it by [aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(VS.80).aspx) tool to include in your sql server instance :

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -E -S localhost -A mr
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.config for the connection string to the database. If it's sql server then there will be a bunch of tables prefixed with 'aspnet_' or something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create the tables and stored procedures for the membership/roles provider you can open a Visual Studio command prompt (check your Start menu) and run `aspnet_regsql`. The `.exe` is also under the `%WINDOWSDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\` directory.

It'll enable you to select a database from a running of Server and create everything you need to be getting on with.